# How to write "ON UPDATE" using orm file

Tags: sql, symfony, orm

I am currently working on symfony2 project. I have one entity caller 'User'. For creating entity I am using orm file. I have created 'User' table using the following snippet.

```
    id:
     id:
        type: integer
        id: true
        generator:
            strategy: AUTO
fields:
    email:
        type: string
        length: '50'
        nullable: true
    password:
        type: text
        nullable: true
    name:
        type: string
        length: '50'
    sex:
        type: boolean
        nullable: true
    mobile:
        type: bigint
        nullable: true
    landline:
        type: bigint
        nullable: true
    dob:
        type: date
        nullable: true
```

Now I want to add two columns "CREATED ON" and "UPDATED ON" which stores the timestamp.
I want something like this

```
     `Created on` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
     `Updated on` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
```

Is there any way for doing this in orm.yml file?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Doctrine Extensions which implement a Timestampable behavior to Doctrine such as explain here:
https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/timestampable.md

But check which version you must use (depend on Doctrine), you can find this info in the README: 
https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions

Comment: Thanks! I found another solution prePersist and preUpdate.

Answer (score 0):

Use https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/timestampable.md

This would be your additional attributes for the ORM

```
createdAt:
    type: datetime
    gedmo:
        timestampable:
            on: create
    column: created_at
updatedAt:
    type: datetime
    gedmo:
        timestampable:
            on: update
    column: updated_at
```